I have problem installing mysql on ubuntu 24.04
I'm encountering problems while trying to install MySQL on my Ubuntu 24.04 system. I'm located in Iran, and I've already tried changing the DNS, using a proxy, and updating the source list, but the issue persists.
Here's what I did:

Ran sudo apt update
Attempted to install MySQL using sudo apt install mysql-server

However, I received the following errors:

Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-core-8.0 amd64 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.24.04.1
404  Not Found [IP: 10.201.176.243 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-8.0 amd64 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.24.04.1
404  Not Found [IP: 10.201.176.243 80]
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-8.0 amd64 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.24.04.1
404  Not Found [IP: 10.201.176.243 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-8.0/mysql-client-core-8.0_8.0.37-0ubuntu0.24.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 10.201.176.243 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-8.0/mysql-client-8.0_8.0.37-0ubuntu0.24.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 10.201.176.243 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-8.0/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.37-0ubuntu0.24.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 10.201.176.243 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

I've also tried running sudo apt-get update and using the --fix-missing flag, but these steps didn't resolve the issue.
Has anyone faced a similar problem or have any suggestions on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance for your help!

All of the errors are reporting that the system cannot reach the web server at address 10.201.176.243. If I try to access that address it times out, which suggests your install request is not going to the correct site.

This may come from an issue with your sources.list.
Try to edit apt sources located here: /etc/apt/sources.list and use those sources:
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security multiverse

Then try again:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server

If updating the sources did not worked, you may can try to install MySQL from the official MySQL APT repository.
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.17-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.17-1_all.deb
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server

If it still does not work, you should look at your DNS.
edit: /etc/resolv.conf and add Goolge's public DNS:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Hope this will help.

thanks for your solution, but I've already tried that, and it didn't work

I updated my response, you should look aat the DNS or try to use MySQL apt repository

That worked, I appreciate it
